# Trouble using hook in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to use hook in codeigniter after perticular function of a controller. As per the documentation it will lead the hook to run after all controllers. But i want my hook to  run after perticular function.

Please help with some example...
Thank You

Comment: Why not append your code to that particular function ??

Comment: Its because i dont want the user to inform that the code is running..I want that process to be in background. I did the process in my site where uploads a video and i have to reduce the video size and take some snapshots of this video. So it takes time which i think i can do in background process something like HOOK .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set few function use hook you can add it to them straightly,
If most function use hook then set hook.And judge particular function in hook.
Here is my example:

config/config.php

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

config/hook.php

```
// I set the hook type to 'post_system', after rendering page hook execute.
$hook['post_system'] = array(
    'class'    => 'HookClass',
    'function' => 'abc',
    'filename' => 'hookClass.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => ''
    );
```

hooks/hookClass.php

```
class HookClass{
    private $particularFunction;
    private $CI;

    function __construct(){
        $this->particularFunction=array('f1','f2');//set particular function name
        $this->CI=& get_instance();                //important!get CI class
    }

    function abc(){
        //if method not in particular function array,execute hook
        if(!in_array($this->CI->router->method, $this->particularFunction))){
            //$this->CI->router->method gets the executing method name
            //execute hooks
        }
    }
}
```

example_controller.php

```
class Example_controller extends CI_controller{
    function f1(){
        //f1 function,and hooks will not execute.
    }
    function d1(){
        //d1 function and hooks will execute 
    }
}
```